# What is the name of this 2x2 curved piece with a lip?

Tags: part-identification

What is this piece called, and what are its degrees?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part number 30602. [Brickset](http://brickset.com/parts/4195869) refers to it as "Front 2x2 Sport" and on [Bricklink](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=30602#T=C) it is "Slope, Curved 2 x 2 Lip, No Studs".

[image: 30602]

The top is curved, so it doesn't have a clean angle like some slopes do and it's name doesn't include an angle measures in degrees.